# How can I use my Wi-Fi (Broadcom BCM43142)?

Tags: networking, drivers

I have tried several things but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please describe the problem with all observable symptoms? You have asked the proverbial dumb question. "My device doesn't work."

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Broadcom BCM43142 has some problems with the Ubuntu 16.04 base kernel that elementary OS Loki uses. There are two solutions for this.

#### Option 1. Install the Kernel built specifically for your Wi-Fi Module

Run the following two commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

#### Option 2. Blacklist the offending items manually.

Edit the blacklist file with this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then append the following lines:

```
blacklist b43
blacklist bcma
blacklist ssb
```